# Testing write speed: ArangoDB...Sync and MSync times

Tags: arangodb

So I'm testing some extreme writes, 10 individual insert...simple for loop (let's keep the topic simple for a moment)...I've got 'wait for sync' turned on for the collection (in this case we need 100% commit when the call returns)... 2 machines... I run the loop on my main machine that I'm running the actual unit test from and it takes 3 minutes to write the 10k... if I write to my remote machine (same arangoDB settings), it takes 9 sec...Is the reason it's taking longer on my local machine due to it also running the unit tests? Or is it due to the SYNC/MSYNC issues of the drive that the arangoDB FAQ warns about?

"From the durability point of view, immediate synchronization is of course better, but it means performing an extra system call for each operation. On systems with slow sync/msync,"

Is there a setting or whatever to check on a drive or system to determine what my values are for the sync/msync of the device?

thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the actual speed strongly depends on your hard disk.

For example for a notebook with SSD under MacOSX I get:

```
arangod> t = time(); for (i = 0;  i < 1000;  i++) db.unsync.save({ name: "Hallo " + i }); time() - t;
0.03408193588256836
arangod> t = time(); for (i = 0;  i < 1000;  i++) db.sync.save({ name: "Hallo " + i }); time() - t;
6.904788970947266
```

So writing 1000 documents is 200x times faster.

For a desktop with harddisk under Linux I get:

```
arangod> t = time(); for (i = 0;  i < 1000;  i++) db.unsync.save({ name: "Hallo " + i }); time() - t;
0.08486199378967285
arangod> t = time(); for (i = 0;  i < 1000;  i++) db.unsync.save({ name: "Hallo " + i }); time() - t;
54.90065908432007
```

Here it is even worse. More than a factor of 600.

Regarding the difference between local and remote: That sounds strange. How do you access the remote machine? Do you use arangosh?

Comment: Ok, I see. As for the one part of the unit test.. This was just using NUnit, C# and HttpWebRequest... I ran the Unit test on the 'remote' machine locally, and it ran just as fast (Windows 7, x64)...100k record inserts in 1 min.. perhaps the initial machine has crappy hard drives then (works fine when waitfor=false)?...But I also noticed that on some test runs (on the machines that things seem to work normal) that 100k inserts take 2 mins. Next set of runs goes back to 1 min... I'm guessing that's the syncing issues?

Comment: You could test your Hard-Drive using "arangosh" when no unit tests are running. That should give you a feeling, how fast your drive is.

Comment: Another remark: If you use many connections in parallel, there is a chance that it gets faster, because "sync" can sync more than one document.